# Python Форматирование вывода списка

Tags: python, list, вывод

Как вывести в функции в return список - вот так?

```
ок 1
ок 2
ок 3
не ок 4
```

сейчас выводится список вот так:

```
[['ок', 1], ['ок', 2], ['ок', 3], ['не ок', 4]]
```

Сама функция

```
def msg():
mes=[]
for number in [1,2,3,4]:
    if number<4:
        mes.append(['ок',number])
    else:
        mes.append(['не ок',number])
return mes
```

UPD:

```
def msg():
    mes=[]
    for number in [1,2,3,4]:
        if number<4:
            mes.append(''.join(map(str,['ок--',number])))
        else:
            mes.append(''.join(map(str,['не ок--',number])))
    return mes
```

Вывод >> `['ок--1', 'ок--2', 'ок--3', 'не ок--4']`

Нужно еще, чтобы перенос строк был

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос, а не редактируйте старый

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
def msg():
    mes=[]
    for number in [1,2,3,4]:
        if number<4:
            mes.append(['ок',number])
        else:
            mes.append(['не ок',number])
    return mes

for x, y in msg():
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: спасибо! а может быть знаете способ, чтобы это выводилось в return?
я сделала вот так

mes.append(''.join(map(str,['ок--',number])))

но в итоге нужен еще перенос строки в выыоде

Comment: @ВарвараКороленкова не понял, что значит выводилось в `return`? Если надо в самой функции вывод, то переместите цикл прямо туда

Comment: @ВарвараКороленкова `return '\n'.join(' '.join(pair) for pair in mes)` - вариант для первого кода